# Haproxy URL route not work corrent

Tags: url-routing, haproxy

I have a API web server, there are two version api coexist, they are routed by url path, which is /shine/v7 and /shine/v8.

I made this by haproxy, but when I request /shine/v7/admin, it sometimes went to shine_v8_backend, and sometimes went to shine_v7_backend, I don't know why this happend, is anyone can help me?

there is my haproxy.conf

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    maxconn 4096
    daemon

defaults
    log     global
    option  http-server-close

frontend http *:5000
    mode tcp
    timeout client 86400000

    default_backend shine_v8_backend
    acl shine_v7    path_dir /shine/v7
    use_backend     shine_v7_backend    if shine_v7


backend shine_v8_backend
    mode tcp
    option httpclose
    balance roundrobin
    timeout server 86400000
    timeout connect 5000
    server host_0 127.0.0.1:5001

backend shine_v7_backend
    mode tcp
    option httpclose
    balance roundrobin
    timeout server 86400000
    timeout connect 5000
    server host_0 127.0.0.1:5002
```

I try to request /shine/v7/admin many times, there is the logs

```
$ sudo haproxy -f haproxy.conf -d
Available polling systems :
     kqueue : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
Total: 3 (2 usable), will use kqueue.
Using kqueue() as the polling mechanism.
00000000:http.accept(0004)=0006 from [127.0.0.1:55026]
00000000:shine_v7_backend.srvcls[0006:0007]
00000000:shine_v7_backend.clicls[0006:0007]
00000000:shine_v7_backend.closed[0006:0007]
00000001:http.accept(0004)=0006 from [127.0.0.1:55028]
00000001:shine_v8_backend.srvcls[0006:0007]
00000001:shine_v8_backend.clicls[0006:0007]
00000001:shine_v8_backend.closed[0006:0007]
00000002:http.accept(0004)=0006 from [127.0.0.1:55030]
00000002:shine_v7_backend.srvcls[0006:0007]
00000002:shine_v7_backend.clicls[0006:0007]
00000002:shine_v7_backend.closed[0006:0007]
00000003:http.accept(0004)=0006 from [127.0.0.1:55032]
00000003:shine_v8_backend.srvcls[0006:0007]
00000003:shine_v8_backend.clicls[0006:0007]
00000003:shine_v8_backend.closed[0006:0007]
00000004:http.accept(0004)=0006 from [127.0.0.1:55034]
00000004:shine_v7_backend.srvcls[0006:0007]
00000004:shine_v7_backend.clicls[0006:0007]
00000004:shine_v7_backend.closed[0006:0007]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, It can't use mode tcp here, must use mode http  :(

and after fix, the haproxy.conf is

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    maxconn 4096
    daemon

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    option  forwardfor
    option  http-server-close

frontend http *:5000
    timeout client 86400000

    acl shine_v8    path_dir /shine/v8
    acl shine_v7    path_dir /shine/v7

    use_backend     shine_v8_backend    if shine_v8
    use_backend     shine_v7_backend    if shine_v7

backend shine_v8_backend
    option httpclose
    balance roundrobin
    timeout server 86400000
    timeout connect 5000
    server host_0 127.0.0.1:5001

backend shine_v7_backend
    option httpclose
    balance roundrobin
    timeout server 86400000
    timeout connect 5000
    server host_0 127.0.0.1:5002
```

it works fine.